# how to filter code completion in visual studio code?

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code to write some web components, and currently not want to use aria-* in any html tags, so I don't want the aria-* and its revelant attributes hints e.g. role, to show up, is there any way to do this? it would be better to show the attributes of a custom element on the first list, e.g. I made my own input field, for the input field which has its own attribute, but after it was created in page, these attributes are not showed up for selection. Thank you very much for your help!